# Implementing sort ASC or DESC in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with an open source school management software, Fedena and I am trying to sort a list of users by their surnames. The software currently shows all users with their first names. I've found these two files to be responsible for showing the information I intend to change.

**student_controller.rb**

```
def list_students_by_course
@students = Student.find_all_by_batch_id(params[:batch_id], :order => 'last_name ASC')
render(:update) { |page| page.replace_html 'students', :partial => 'students_by_course' }
end
```

When I delete the above section of the file, the users names don't show up so I believe this section to be responsible for populating the table with the usernames.

**_students_by_course.erb**

```
<div class="students-table">
  <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr class="tr-head">
      <td><%= t('sl_no') %></td>
      <td><%= t('name') %></td>
      <td><%= t('adm_no') %></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <% @students.each_with_index do |r, i| %>
      <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
        <td class="col-1">
          <%= i+1 %>
        </td>

        <td class="col-2">
          <%= link_to r.full_name,:controller => "student", :action => "profile", :id => r.id %>
        </td>

        <td class="col-1">
          <%= r.admission_no %>
        </td>

        <td class="col-7">
          <%=  link_to  "#{t('view_profile')}", :controller => "student", :action => "profile", :id => r.id %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have tried changing 'last_name ASC' to 'last_name DESC' but nothing changed. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what version of rails?

Comment: You haven't really asked a question here, so I'm not sure exactly what you're saying the problem is. I'm inferring that you currently have ASC sort and want DESC sort, but it's not changing? Does the `Student` model have a default scope defined on it that enforces a sort?

Comment: @Anthony I have Ruby 1.8.7 installed with version 2.3.5 of Rails.

Comment: @Lurker: Sorry, I'm a PHP programmer and I'm only starting to get my feet wet with Ruby. Should I post the full files on pastie and include links here?

Comment: If you made a change on a server running in production, you need to restart the application server. In production mode it caches most of the app's code and changes in source files are not reflected. `development` mode doesn't so this. If this is all irrelevant, clarify how are you running the app and what changes exactly did you make.

Comment: You don't need to paste all the files. But you do need to know what's going on inside the model. Look in the model for a line that says `default_scope`.

Comment: This is the [project](https://github.com/projectfedena/fedena). The files I edited are under "app/controllers" (ruby) and "app/views" (html/.erb). Click [here](http://104.131.254.52:8088/student/view_all) and use admin/admin123 - On that link, after selecting the only batch, you'd find 2 users. Now, instead of 'Barack Obama', I want it to read 'Obama Barack'. I hope I've made this clear enough. If you require any information to grasp things better, please let me know. @lurker

Comment: @D-side, thanks for the tip. I hope with my last post you understand what I'm trying to achieve better. The link I provided is on the cloud, but I have a local instance of the same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've clarified in the comments that you want not sort order (I take it you've figured that out?) but the **format** of **full name** displayed for **each** instance of a model `Student`.

It's not hard if traced to the source. Let's start with a view, since that's what we see.

```
@students.each_with_index do |r, i|
```

We start a loop, each iteration of which processes an entry `r` with an index `i`. Since we're looping on a collection of `Student`s (seems like a valid assumption), `r` is an instance of `Student`. The problematic line is:

```
<%= link_to r.full_name,:controller => "student", :action => "profile", :id => r.id %>
```

Actually, we should only look at `r.full_name` since that's what we get as a link label. It's a `Student`'s method. [Here it is](https://github.com/projectfedena/fedena/blob/master/app/models/student.rb#L140).

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

You might be wondering where is a second space, since such implementation implies that if `middle_name` is absent, we'd have two. Look at the source of the page and you'll see that there are actually two! So in order to change how the full name looks, you'll have to modify this method.

Comment: Thank you very much for that concrete answer, @D-side. Initially, I had jumped the gun and got this working by replacing every instance of first_name with last_name in "models\students.rb" but later reversed those changes and updated the file according to your instructions and it works as expected. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be a separate question, but I might as well just stick in a comment since it's related: Although it works as expected, the list is sorted based on their IDs (Serial no.). I would like to sort them using the #{last_name}. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: @students.sort_by(&:last_name)

Comment: I still need help. I was able to get this working for the "Manage Users" module by replacing `:order =>'id ASC'` with `:order =>'last_name ASC'`in "controllers\user_controller.rb" but still can't get this to work for the students module "controllers\student_controller.rb". I've also looked into "models/students.rb". Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlexChaffee I searched the files for `@students.sort_by` and didn't find that line. Where should I look?

Comment: you type it yourself -- instead of `@students.each_with_index` do `@students.sort_by(&:last_name).each_with_index`

Comment: @AlexChaffee That took care of it. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: The Rails way of solving this is through an `order`-clause, to get entries already sorted from the database. Using `sort_by` sorts already fetched entries in RAM and brings some heavy logic to a view. It should't cause any major performance issues here, but it's not considered good MVC practice.

Comment: True enough, @D-side. I missed the controller source code above. Clearly there's a problem since `Student.find_all_by_batch_id(params[:batch_id], :order => 'last_name ASC')` isn't sorting. I would try `Student.where(batch_id: params[:batch_id]).order(:last_name)` since that matches the more modern Rails query style.

Comment: @AlexChaffee You should look at SQL that your queries generate and look for issues. Don't rush at newer syntax if you haven't upgraded the app to a newer version of Rails.